# streaming files in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just uploaded files(doc & pdf) in my web server(with my coding). I want to stream those files when I click download link on my page.

please share any tutorials or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used send_file in ruby..

```
send_file(file_to_send, :disposition => "attachment")
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you store them? On disk? In database?
The send_file is the api function that sends the file ...
Also, read this: http://john.guen.in/past/2007/4/17/send_files_faster_with_xsendfile/